# Which type I should use to save many objects with same key? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Which type I should use to save many objects with same key?

I should post data to server where one of parameter is suggestedTo and it contains userId.
This parameters should be more then one. So I'm confused which data type I should use to save them.
For example array or dictionary should looks like

```
{
  @"suggestedTo" = 111,
  @"suggestedTo" = 222,
  @"suggestedTo" = 333,
  etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically handled with a dictionary of sets (or arrays if the data is ordered). So in this case, you'd have something like:

```
NSSet *suggestedTo = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:111],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:222],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:333], nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:suggestedTo,
                                                                @"suggestedTo", nil];
```

Comment: @Paul.s
Doesn't works for me. The url should be like

somesite/do/service/suggest?message=TEST&postId=5YsZrEPvH1&suggestedTo=LIaJbMuuH1&suggestedTo=JaADJdh

But I have 

somesite/do/service/suggest?message=TEST&postId=5YsZrEPvH1&suggestedTo[]=LIaJbMuuH1

I'm using AFHHTPClient library to send request. Maybe I should use something else?
Because I don't want to use loop and send request each iteration.

Comment: @artyom, was this comment on the correct question? I'm not certain how it relates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary of arrays

```
NSArray      *suggestedTos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:111],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:222],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:333], nil];

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               suggestedTos, @"suggestedTo", nil];
```